# Javascript datatable pagination and custom attributes getting undesirable trimmed strings

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, datatable

Got this Ajax in my template where i receive a json response and append the elements of that json into a datatable:

```
$('.bicam_tests').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'http://10.1.1.150/humanresource/testsql.php?user_id=&user_id=&option=total_quizes_json',
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false,
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
        success: function (response) {
            $("#id_bicam_datatable tbody").html("");
            $.each(response, function(i, item) {
                $("#id_bicam_datatable tbody").append('<tr><td>'+ item.id +'</td><td>'+ item.course +'</td><td>'+ item.name +'</td><td>'+'<input class="form-check-input" name="bicam_check" type="checkbox" fid=' + item.id  + ' fcourse=' + item.course + ' fname=' + item.name + '></td></tr>');
            });
            init_datatable("#id_bicam_datatable");
        },
        error:
        function(data){
            alert("Response error");
        }
    });
});
```

I'm having two issues:

- I can't get the datatable to paginate the records
- The custom attributes I'm setting (fid, fcourse and fname)  are receiving a trimmed string,it's like javascript it's cutting the strings by itself and creating separated attributes but i checked concatenations and they're ok. Also, consolelog doesn't shows errors at all.

This is the custom method im using for datatable init:

```
function init_datatable(element, option){
    var element = element || ".datatable";
    var option_sorting = [[0,'asc']];
    if(option == "no-order"){
        option_sorting = [];
    }
    $("" + element).DataTable({
        'lengthChange': true,
        'searching'   : true,
        'destroy'     : true,
        'ordering'    : true,
        'info'        : true,
        'autoWidth'   : true,
        'aaSorting'   : option_sorting,
        "language": {
            "url": "//"+ XPS_ +"/datatables/lang/Spanish.json"
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to enclose in quotes the variable concatenation (javascript + HTML):

```
$('.bicam_tests').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'http://10.1.1.150/humanresource/testsql.php?user_id=&user_id=&option=total_quizes_json',
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false,
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
        success: function (response) {
            $("#id_bicam_datatable tbody").html("");
            $.each(response, function(i, item) {
                $("#id_bicam_datatable tbody").append('<tr><td>'+ item.id +'</td><td>'+ item.course +'</td><td>'+ item.name +'</td><td>'+'<input class="form-check-input" name="bicam_check" type="checkbox" fid="' + item.id  + '" fcourse="' + item.course + '" fname="' + item.name + '"></td></tr>');
            });
            init_datatable("#id_bicam_datatable");
        },
        error:
        function(data){
            alert("Response error");
        }
    });
});
```

If quotes are not set, it prints:

```
<input class="form-check-input" name="bicam_check" type="checkbox" fid=item  fcourse=XXX text of course fname=YYY text of name>
```

The DOM show this:

```
<input class="form-check-input" name="bicam_check" type="checkbox" fid=item  fcourse=XXX text="" of="" course="" fname=YYY text="" of="" name="">
```

The correct way is enclose in quotes if you expect a string (with spaces). Quotation marks are not required for Integer type fields.

```
fcourse="' + item.course + '"
```

For the Datatable function, i recommend adding this attribute:

```
pagination: true,
```

However, with the concatenation correction, it must work.